# Checking the value that is being assigned to an object's attribute

Tags: scala

I would like to define a class that wraps mac addresses:

```
class MacAddress(macAddress: String)
```

However, I'd like to check that the value passed as parameter is indeed a mac address. Does this make sense, and if so what is the proper way to achieve this in Scala?

The best I could come up with is the following:

```
class MacAddress private (macAddress: String)
object MacAddress {
  // TODO: Here we would validate that the passed string is indeed a MAC address.
  def apply(macAddress: String): Try[MacAddress] = ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `require` to validate an argument. Here's an example with a regex:

```
case class MacAddress(macAddress: String) {
  require(macAddress.matches("^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$"), "Invalid mac address")
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> MacAddress("00:0a:95:9d:68:1A")
res11: MacAddress = MacAddress(00:0a:95:9d:68:1A)

scala> MacAddress("00:0a:95:9d:68:1Z")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Invalid mac address
at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:277)
... 28 elided
```